# Google not index website because of Http Header Redirect

Tags: asp.net-mvc, seo, google-search-console

hi webmasters i have been developed a web site with the asp.net mvc5 framework
[www.esfandbar.com](http://esfandbar.com)
i am new to SEO and i ask google to index my web site in google webmaster for about one month but google does not index that and total index is 0 when i inspect the problem with the http://www.siteliner.com i find out that except the home page all another page
skipped with the **Http Header Redirect** look at this photo please

[image]

all of my work for SEO is setting the rules in web.config file for:

1. redirect all the none www to www
2. redirect all the http request to https
3. remove the ending shash(/) from the Urls

how can i solve this problem? thank you for your time

this is redirection rule in web.config

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
  <rule name="rule" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{URL}" pattern="[A-Z]" ignoreCase="false" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="{ToLower:{URL}}" redirectType="Permanent" />
  </rule>
  <rule name="RemoveTrailingSlashRule1" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)/$" />
    <conditions>
      <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
      <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}" />
  </rule>
<rule name="Rewrite domain requests" stopProcessing="true" enabled="true">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www.)?([.a-zA-Z0-9]+)$" />
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\.esfandbar\.com$" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.esfandbar.com/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="true" />
</rule>
        <rule name="HTTP/S to HTTPS Redirect" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="(.*)" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
          <add input="{SERVER_PORT_SECURE}" pattern="^0$" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>

</rules>
</rewrite>
```